# Recursively obtain a list of all permissions on Windows file shares

Tags: network-share, windows, permissions

I have been assigned a task as the new guy on the IT team at where I work to list and document all the assigned permissions for every single directory in the entire directory tree of the file shares on the server that runs the shares for the company.

I do know it's running Windows Server, but I don't remember the specific version offhand.  I also know that the user groups to control access are in Active Directory, but I haven't been given access to the AD server for this.

Is there some easier way to get the assigned permissions for every single directory in the directory tree of the shares recursively, without me going into every single folder by hand to identify the permissions?

Comment: http://www.cjwdev.co.uk/Software/NtfsReports/Info.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a script.  :)

Googling turned up a [Get Share Permissions](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a231026a-3fdb-4190-9915-38d8cd827348) PowerShell module download.  It's free and looks like it does what you're looking for.

You might also be interested in this:  [AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx) from SysInternals.

Comment: Both of those look like they'll do what I need.  I don't have access to PowerShell on the server in question, so I'll need to have the sysadmin review either of these options and give me access to the server itself to run one of these one.  I may be on the IT team, but I don't have the same access as the sysadmin does, nor the same rights to do a security review on the solutions.  This does seem like it'll do what I need, though!

Comment: The only thing I don't like about AccessEnum (which I'm now running as a test to see how it defines these things on my personal server running here at home) is that it doesn't give me the option to only show directories.  I don't think that's a huge issue, it's just a little bit annoying that that's the case.

Comment: Take a look at the command-line version Sysinternals `AccessChk` which offers the `-d` option to only process directories or top level key.